# configure language domains for search engines - SEO

Tags: subdomain, seo

I have a site that uses different language (*http://www.boletus-app.com*). Each language is displayed in a different subdomain (*http://en.boletus-app.com*, *http://es.boletus-app.com*, etc.). The main site (*www*) shows the language used by the user in previous entries or the browser one by default.
Which strategy should I use so that Google identifies this? People usually links to *www* site.

What I have currently done is adding the alternate tag:

`<link href="http://es.boletus-app.com" rel="alternate" hreflang="es"/>`

Is there anything I can do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell Google about language specific versions of your website in three different ways. One among them is your current way using `rel="alternate" hreflang="x"` annotation. Please note that this markup is seen as one of the signals and not as a directive to the Google Crawler..

You may find additional information under [this webmaster tools link](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=189077&topic=2370587&ctx=topic)

Also, you should go through this [Internationalisation FAQ](https://sites.google.com/site/webmasterhelpforum/en/faq-internationalisation) by Google Webmaster Central where it is clearly mentioned that the Google Crawler detects the language on a per-URL basis and there's no need to use any special structure. However, it’s important that each language version is on a separate URL, and that Googlebot is able to crawl all versions.

So, imho and as stated in the links stated above, you are on a comfortable position with your current style.